# Launch a specific project in a multi-project workspace in VSCode (.NET)

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

Trying out VSCode, and encountering this workspace configuration conundrum:

Everything used to be in the root workspace dir under a single project, but I have created a test project. Now I have a multi-project setup (no solution file) that looks like this:

```
MySolution/
│
├── .vscode/
│   ├── launch.json
│   └── tasks.json
│
├── MyProject/
│   ├── Properties/
│   │   └── launchSettings.json
│   ├── MyProject.csproj
│   └── ...
│
└── MyProject.Tests/
    └── MyProject.Tests.csproj
```

The problem is, this setup ignores the `launchSettings.json` file, and I haven't been able to figure out how to point to it from `launch.json` (or if it's at all possible).

If I move the run configurations to the project level, then the project runs successfully and takes the launch settings into account, but not from the VSCode UI: I am unable to add a run configuration that just uses the `launch.json` file in the new location. Opening only the project folder in VSCode might help, but it would make it very inconvenient to work with the tests, so I'd rather not do that.

I'd like to either be able to tell the run configuration which `launchSettings` file to use, or use the project `launch.json` file as the workspace default. Is either possible?